# How to use preg_replace over two lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a `preg_replace` pattern to use to replace text that is back-to-back across two lines.  I want to convert this:

```
... </li></ul>
<ul><li> ...
```

to this:

```
... </li>
<li> ...
```

or this:

```
... </li><li> ...
```

Of course, `$pattern = "/<\/ul><ul>/"` and `$replacement = ""` produces what I'm looking for if the `ul` tags are in the same row.  However, as soon as there is a newline between the `ul` tags, the pattern fails.

The pattern `$pattern = "/<\/ul>.*<ul>/s"` works in the isolated case, but it is horrible when it comes to

```
... </li></ul>

... THIS IS SOME VALUABLE CONTENT ...

<ul><li> ...
```

I know there must be a `\n`, a `\r`, `<br \/>`, or some combination that needs to go between the `ul` tags, but I haven't been able to find the right solution.

(I understand that there is potentially a better solution than `preg_replace` for the case outlined above, but it is one in a series of pattern and replace pairs that I am using iteratively in a parser, so I want to stick with it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to replace the `ul` tags across two lines with possible whitespace ...

```
$str = preg_replace('~</ul>\R*<ul>~', '', $str);
```

Otherwise, if trying to replace everything between; add a non-greedy quantifier to your regex.

```
$str = preg_replace('~</ul>.*?<ul>~s', '', $str);
```